# Accessing Admin on DB2 Dev on Mac

Tags: db2, passwords, admin

I installed the IBM DB2 Developer Community Edition a while ago and when I wanted to log in to the Data Server Manager I realised I forgot my pasword.

DB2 tells me to contact the OS administrator to reset the pw. I am the admin but I have idea whatsoever how to do this on a Mac.

Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

The Data Server Manager password is set when DSM is first set-up.

If you stop the DSM server

```
ibm-datasrvrmgr/bin/stop.sh
```

then run the setup again, you will be prompted to setup a password again

```
ibm-datasrvrmgr/setup.sh
```

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS5Q8A_2.1.x/com.ibm.datatools.dsweb.ots.installconfig.doc/topics/installing_quick.html